# 4 errores en mi php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola los errores que me aparecen son estos:

**Undefined variable: con**

**mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given**

**Undefined variable: con**

**mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given**

Este es mi codigo **php**

```
<?php
require_once "Conexion.php";
require_once "Producto.php";
class Data{

    private $con;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->con = new Conexion("localhost", "ventas", "root", "");
    }

    public function getProductos(){
        $productos = array();

        $query =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM producto");

        while($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$query)){
            $p = new Producto();

            $P->id = $reg[0];
            $P->nombre = $reg[1];
            $P->precio = $reg[2];
            $P->stock = $reg[3];

            array_push($productos, $p);
        }

        return $productos;
    }
}
?>
```

Mi base de datos **MySQL**

```
create database ventas;

use ventas;

create table producto(
    id int auto_increment,
    nombre varchar(100),
    precio int,
    stock int,
    primary key(id)
);

insert into producto values(null,'Labial','10','10');
insert into producto values(null,'Cejas','20','20');
insert into producto values(null,'Crema','30','30');
insert into producto values(null,'Rimel','40','40');
insert into producto values(null,'Polvo','50','50');

create table venta(
    id int auto_increment,
    fecha datetime,
    total int,
    primary key(id)
);

create table detalle(
    id int auto_increment,
    venta int,
    producto int,


cantidad int,
    subTotal int,
    primary key(id)
);
```

Por favor díganme la solución llevo tiempo en esto :).

Comment: veo que los valores de conexión a mysqli los pasas así: ` $this->con = new Conexion("localhost", "ventas", "root", "");` pero mysqli los pide así `servidor, usuario, contraseña y basededatos`

Comment: otra cosa que veo rara, es por que si el `id` de tu tabla es PK y `AUTO_INCREMENT` le pones un valor de `NULL` cuando a ese campo tu no le debes asignar valor alguno puesto que con las características antes mencionadas es el propio gestor el que dará un valor

Comment: @alfap Lo reescribe tal como lo comentaste pero ahora hay otro error, mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: `$this->con = new Conexion("localhost", "tu_usuario", "tu_contraseña", "ventas");`